# Python - Pandas : Add incrementation number to an exisiting column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with several columns.

example data :

```
d = {'col1': ['A','B','C','D']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I'm trying to modify col1 and add "_1", "_2"

To get something like that:

```
     col1
 0    A_1
 1    B_2
 2    C_3
 3    D_4
```

I tried to do something like that :

```
df_final['col1'] = df_final['col1'].apply(lambda x: str(x)+str(df_final[x].index))
```

But I got error:

```
KeyError: 'A'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `1` to index, convert to string and add to column if default index in `DataFrame`:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'] + '_' + (df.index + 1).astype(str)
print (df)
  col1
0  A_1
1  B_2
2  C_3
3  D_4
```

---

If not default `RangeIndex`:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'] + '_' + pd.RangeIndex(1, len(df) + 1).astype(str)
```

Or use `f-string`s with `enumerate`:

```
df['col1'] = [f'{b}_{a}' for a, b in enumerate(df['col1'], 1)]
print (df)
  col1
0  A_1
1  B_2
2  C_3
3  D_4
```

Comment: Perfect, it's what i was looking for